# does Java.io.InputStream.read() Method read every datatype as byte?

Tags: java, io

if the read method reads a byte of data from the input stream,
 when it has to read a char, does it read twice byte by byte? as a char is of 2 byes?

Comment: why don't you use readChar in the DataInputStream class?

Comment: All data is bytes, and `read()` returns a single byte.

Comment: It *doesn't* have to 'read a `char`'. It is specified to read bytes, and that's what it does. Your question doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

`InputStream` operates on bytes. It is the underlying I/O abstraction in Java. It can read a single byte or a sequence of bytes, depending on what the caller requests. But it knows nothing about characters, so it cannot, by itself, decide to read two bytes for a character. A `Reader` would have to request this.

If you need to read characters, use [`Reader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html) to read them from the `InputStream`.

(Similarly, to read serialized Java objects, you would use [`ObjectInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html), which again reads them from the `InputStream`. Or you can use [`Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) to read a variety of inputs from numbers to text, again from an `InputStream`.)

The purpose of this abstraction is separation of responsibilities -

- The `InputStream` provides a stream of bytes and handles all underlying logic (file reading / network / ...).
- The `Reader` converts the stream of bytes to stream of characters, and doesn't care where the data came from.

Answer (score 0):

As per Oracle documentation available online https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read() it reads Byte Array

Comment: Or a single byte.